# Nexus proxy to node-sass-binaries

Tags: github, sass, nexus3

I am behind a corporate proxy, so my build can't download the `node-sass-binaries` directly from github. For now I have a `Nexus3 raw repository (hosted).` The  biniary files are downloaded from `https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/{version}/{artifact}` and I upload them manually to the repository. In the `.npmrc` I reference my repository with `node-sass-binary={path to repo}` and it works fine. But I don't want to manually download and upload the files every time a new one is needed.

Now I want to set up a proxy repository that gets the artifacts automatically (like it is working with maven central).

What have I tried? I have created an `Raw (proxy)` repo and entered the download URL `https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/`

[image]

But this isn't working.

The error I get:

> node-sass@4.11.0 install C:\Project\ng\src\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js
>
> Downloading binary from https://myserver/nexus/repository/node-sass-binary//v4.11.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node
>   Cannot download "https://myserver/nexus/repository/node-sass-binary//v4.11.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node":
>
> HTTP error 404 Not Found
>
> Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
>         try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.
>
> ```
>  export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
> ```
>
> or configure npm proxy via
>
> ```
>  npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
> ```
>
> node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall C:\Project\ng\src\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/build.js

In my opinion this error message makes sense because if I call `https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/` directly in the browser I get a 404 message.

So am I using the wrong URL or do I miss something else? Is it even possible to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try using npm (proxy) instead of raw (proxy) ?

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. Why this shoulde be an npm repository, the node-sass-binaries doesn't have an npm structure?

Comment: i have the same problem i think. i am proxying npm to get ibm_db but then ibm_db downloads a big gz file from ibm.com. ibm.com is https but my proxy is http. so i'm doing a raw proxy for that gz file...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
I believe you are using Node v12 which is not supported with node-sass@4.11.0

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.11.0

and for this reason win32-x64-72_binding.node is not found (72 refers to Node v.12 ...)
So, use node-sass 4.12.0 or higher in order to fix this issue.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. node-sass repository can't be proxied for automatic donwloading behind a corporate proxy.

Comment: i was able to configure the proxy using Nexus3 with the same configuration you used (with only one differeence i.e. checking the flag "use the Nexus TrustStore") and i'm behing a HTTP proxy. The error you have is instead due to wrong version of node-sass library because no version_72 exists for node-sass@4.11.0 ....

Comment: Okay, I will try this. Although I don't really need it anymore because Angular switched from node-sass to dart-sass. Thanks for your help